# React Component becomes undefined after second drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dnd

When I drag and drop a Component into my Box and then try to drag and drop the element in another Box, that looks the same from the code. I get an error. How could I fix that? It should be possible to drag and drop the component in every box.

Here the Error:

> ERROR
> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Box`.
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Here the code:

```
import { FC, useState, createElement, memo } from 'react';
import { useDrop, useDrag, DragSourceMonitor } from 'react-dnd';
import { ItemTypes } from '../constants/ItemTypes';

const Box: FC<any> = ({ prop }) => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState<any>();
    const [, drop] = useDrop<any>(() => ({
        accept: ItemTypes.BOX,
        drop(itemDrag, monitor) {
            console.log(typeof(itemDrag));
            console.log(itemDrag)
            setItem(itemDrag);
        },
        collect: monitor => ({
            isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        }),
    }));
    const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: ItemTypes.BOX,
        item: { item: item },
        canDrag: item,
        collect: (monitor: DragSourceMonitor) => ({
            isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
        })
    }));
    return (
        <div ref={drop} style={{ backgroundColor: "#FF0000" }}>
            {prop}
            {item && (
                <div ref={drag}>
                    {createElement(item.item)}
                </div>
                )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default memo(Box);
```

I found out, that the React Component becomes undefined while the second drop:

console.log in the drop function of useDrop hook:

First drop from Container:

> Objectitem: () => {…}[[Prototype]]: Object

Second drop from Box:

> Objectitem: undefined[[Prototype]]: Object

I found additional out, that if I use the useDrag within the component it self the issue is not there, only if I use my DragWrapper Component. But I want to use it, it will spare me copy and paste and will make it easer to change (but you know all that :-))
Additional here the code from the DragWrapper component:

```
import { ComponentType, FC, ReactNode, createElement } from 'react';
import { useDrag, DragSourceMonitor } from 'react-dnd';
import { ItemTypes } from '../constants/ItemTypes';

interface DragWrapperType {
    child: ComponentType<any>
    props?: Object
}

const DragWrapper: FC<DragWrapperType> = ({ child, props }) => {
    const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: ItemTypes.BOX,
        item: { item: child },
        collect: (monitor: DragSourceMonitor) => ({
            isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
        })
    }))
    return (
        <div ref={drag}>
            {child && createElement(child, props)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default DragWrapper;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So issue solved.

It seems like the Object was undefined, because it was from the beginning undefined. I guess the useDrag hook was at the beginning initialized and never changed throw the useStat hook.

To solve the issue I just had to get sure, the useDrag hook initialize when there is a defined object, I used the DragWrapper for that:

```
{item && item.item &&(
     <DragWrapper child={item.item} />
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ref={drop} style={{ backgroundColor: "#FF0000" }}>
  {prop} {item && item.item && ( 
  <div ref={drag}>
    {createElement(item.item)}
  </div>
  )}
</div>
```

I believe what is happening here is that the component Box is being rendered even before the item is defined by the drop state. Hence trying to wait for the item to be defined might solve your prob. If it doesn't, please link up a dev fiddle with the rest of your impl.
The difference is the addition of `{item && item.item && ...}` to ensure that `item.item` is defined before rendering it with createElement. This change prevents the "undefined" error during the second drop.

Comment: Yeah the error is away but the bug and the console.log is the same xD.
I am not sure what is a dev fiddle, but I recorded now the performance with Firefox and uploaded the file to GitHub:
https://github.com/psurac/fancy-cv-maker/blob/master/Firefox%202023-10-11%2021.59%20profile.json.gz
(In there is the rest of the code so far.)
If you need more let me know.
Thank you!